# Use function in Django Include Tag?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to pass a value into a template via an include tab, like so:

```
{% include "shared/page_title.html" with text=local_time_format(job.date, user.timezone, "M j P") %}
```

So basically, i want the `text` value to be the result of calling `local_time_format` (a filter function) with `job.date` (context object value) and a `user` property and the final argument.

Getting `Could not parse the remainder` error-- how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prep values for an include like so:

```
{% with text=today|date:"D d M Y" %}
{% include "shared/page\_title.html" with text=text%}
{% endwith %}
```